Objective function in Bayesian Hyperparameter Tuning
I have a question that has been going around in my head for a while and I'd like to leverage the wisdom of the crowd for getting a few opinions on it.
Let me describe the Problem:
I have a relatively small dataset (600 samples) and I want to train a classifier that predicts a few classes (either binary or multiclass up to 4 classes, depending on the problem statement). To do this, I selected a few models that I would expect to work on small datasets (Logistic Regression, SVM, Random Forest), defined a parameter space including regularization chosen by an educated guess (e.g. strongly limiting the depth of the Trees in the RF) and performed standard bayesian optimization using a 5-fold cross validation strategy, optimizing the f1 (macro f1 for multiclass) score.
Now I want to describe my problem/observation:
Whenever I run the optimization, I select the best performing model based on the test score, which is overfitting (+0.1-0.2 score difference) for all the model types. Right now, I can't get more data and I would like to avoid searching for the right parameter space (hence Bayesian optimization) in a tedious process of repeated searching.
One potential solution I have been pondering is changing my objective function to penalize overfitting:
For each fold in my cross validation calculate the score on the test and train set and substract the difference between them from my test score to penalize overfitting, while keeping the objective of getting the best test score.
I'm wondering, if this would be a problem, potentially introducing information leakage. Maybe of interest, there are still two additional test sets: a hold-out of the original dataset and an independent dataset.
Is there a term for the approach I have been thinking of? Are there publications/resources covering this topic?
